# Passing a parameter to a Javascript function using data attributes in an <a> tag in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC 5 web app using Visual Studio 2013.

I am trying to create a list of Courses using anchor tags which when clicked will pass as a parameter the selected Course to a Javascript function. The Javascript function will in turn use Ajax to call a second function to retrieve a list of Students enrolled on the selected Course.

In the View I have:

```
@model  IEnumerable<School.Models.Course>

...

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a class='selectedCourse' onclick='JavaScript:selectedCourse()' data-cname="@item.CourseName">@item.CourseName</a>
}
```

The Course list gets created as expected:

```
<a class='selectedCourse' onclick='JavaScript:selectedCourse()' data-cname="Chemistry">Chemistry</a>
<a class='selectedCourse' onclick='JavaScript:selectedCourse()' data-cname="Physics">Physics</a>
```

My Javascript function is defined as follows:

```
function selectedCourse() {
var selectedCourseName = $(this).data('cname');
}
```

The code reaches the Javascript function but the value of selectedCourseName is always 'undefined'.

Am I missing something really basic for this to work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Walter

Comment: code seems fine.. are you getting any errors in your console ??

Comment: Seems like it should work. Any reason why you're adding the handler inline? Generally you want to keep your code separate from your markup.  `$('.selectedCourse').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var selectedCourseName = $(this).data('cname'); ...});` See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/N4S9N/

Comment: Thank you tvanfosson. I made the change you suggested in your jsfiddle and it now works. Thanks again. How can I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: @WalterLockhart - posted an explanation of why it doesn't work along with my recommendation as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it's not working is because the context of `this` on an inline event handler is not the element itself, but the window element.  Change your code so that the handler is applied separately from your markup, this is a best practice anyway, and the context will be correct.

```
 $('.selectedCourse').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var selectedCourseName = $(this).data('cname');
     ...
 });
```

An alternative, and one I don't recommend, is to add a parameter to your inline handler and pass `this` as the parameter.  The value of the parameter will be the element that was clicked.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="foo(this);">Don't do this!</a>
```

See examples at http://jsfiddle.net/cJZpK/